# jQuery Creating a dynamic list out of amount of divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So basically what I have is an amount of divs inside of an article, basically like this:

```
<article class="post">
  <div class = "page-content 1"></div>
  <div class = "page-content 2"></div>
  <div class = "page-content 3"></div>
  <div class = "page-content 4"></div>
  <div class = "page-content 5"></div>
</article>
```

Now taking those divs I want to create a list based upon those divs looking pretty much like this:

```
<ul>
<li>Content1</li>
<li>Content2</li>
<li>Content3</li>
<li>Content4</li>
<li>Content5</li>
</ul>
```

The "ContentX" text inside the list is not required. Basically in the end it's supposed to be a site navigation.
Up to now I tried to get the amount of divs needed stored in a variable and then based upon this variable create the list.

This is to get the amount of divs and my first attempt at creating the list:

```
var divAmount = jQuery(' .post > div').length;
jQuery("<ul id='newList'></ul>"); 
for (i = 0; cnt < divAmount; i++) { 
  $("#newList").append("<li></li>"); 
})
```

I just have no clue how to create such a list from scratch. Might be quite the easy task for you guys here but I'm very new to jQuery and basically have no idea what I'm doing...

Comment: What have you tried, please show us

Comment: Try [here first](https://learn.jquery.com/) then come back when you've tried some examples. Teach a man to fish etc, etc

Comment: This is to get the amount of divs: var divAmount = jQuery(' .post > div').length; - And this to create the list inside a div with the ID newList: jQuery("<ul id='newList'></ul>");
                    for (i = 0; cnt < divAmount; i++) {
                        $("#newList").append("<li></li>");
                    }
                )

Comment: Added a JSFiddle, that might help: https://jsfiddle.net/z09mnhd6/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$("body").append("<ul></ul>");

$("article div").each(function(){
var content=$(this).attr("class").replace("page-", "")
$("ul").append("<li>"+content+"</li>");
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<article class="post">
  <div class = "page-content 1"></div>
  <div class = "page-content 2"></div>
  <div class = "page-content 3"></div>
  <div class = "page-content 4"></div>
  <div class = "page-content 5"></div>
</article>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Solved the issue with that

Comment: @Mole welcome, please don't forget to click on the **Check Mark** to set the answer approved